# Making a Star Triangle in SML

Tags: recursion, sml, smlnj

I have just started coding in SMLNJ and have been having some trouble making a program that returns a string in a triangular star pattern. For example triangle(5) should output:

```
*****
****
***
**
*
```

My code so far is:

```
fun triangle(x) =  
    if (x = 0) then "\n"  
    else   
        let  
            fun makeTriangle(n) =  
                if(n = 0) then "\n" else "*"^makeTriangle(n-1);  
        in  
            makeTriangle(x);  
        end  
        triangle(x-1)
```

I am getting the error "triangle.sml:9.3 Error: syntax error: inserting EQUALOP". Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two issues with your code:

First, there is a simple operator precedence issue:

```
if(n = 0) then "\n" else "*"^makeTriangle(n-1)
```

parses as

```
(if(n = 0) then "\n" else "*") ^ makeTriangle(n-1)
```

rather than your intended

```
if(n = 0) then "\n" else ("*" ^ makeTriangle(n-1))
```

The solution is to put in the needed parentheses.

Another issue is the stray line `triangle(x-1)` at the bottom of the function. It is unrelated to the code above it. If your intention is to concatenate it to the result of the function call `makeTriangle(x)` then you would need to do the explicit concatenation. There really shouldn't be anything in your function definition after the `end` since that `end` terminates the `else` part.

A minor issue: since your function `makeTriangle` inserts `"\n"`, your code (after fixed) will have *two* `"\n"` at the bottom of the triangle. If that isn't what you want, perhaps you can think about the basis case (`n=0`).

Answer (score 1):

Since John already explained some of the issues with your code, and since this seems like an exercise, here are two ways you could solve it differently:

1. Recursively, using pattern matching:

   ```
   fun repeat (0, _) = []
     | repeat (n, x) = x :: repeat (n-1, x)

   fun triangle 0 = ""
     | triangle n = implode (repeat (n, #"*")) ^ "\n" ^ triangle (n-1)
   ```
2. There's a library function called `List.tabulate` of which `repeat` is a special case:

   ```
   fun repeat (n, x) = List.tabulate (n, fn _ => x)
   ```

   But actually, `triangle` itself fits pretty well within `List.tabulate`:

   ```
   fun triangle n =
       concat (List.tabulate (n, fn i => implode (repeat (15 - i, #"*")) ^ "\n"))
   ```